# How do you show that $u+w+v = 0$ given $u \times v = v \times w = w \times u$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, cross-product

Given that $u+w+v = 0$, I was able to prove that $u \times v = v \times w = w \times u$ by using the anti-commutative property.

But I'm struggling a lot with how to approach to prove the converse. Given $u,v,w$ are pairwise non-parallel vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

Comment: Your title uses scalar multiplication, your question uses vector cross product (I assume, since otherwise it's simply false). Please clarify!

Comment: I edited your post to demonstrate how to format equations. Please modify your title to match.

Comment: Hint: If vectors $ a \times b = 0$, then $ a = k b$ for some constant $k$.

Comment: I assume $u,v,w \ne 0$. Otherwise if *e.g*  $w=0$ you will have $u \times v=0$ or $u=kv$ and $u+v+w=(k+1)v$ that is not always zero

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't true.  Try $u = v = w \ne 0$.

EDIT: If you add the extra condition that the vectors are pairwise non-collinear, it is true.

Note that $a \times b = 0$ if and only if $a$ and $b$ are collinear.

The condition $u \times v = v \times w$ is equivalent to $(u + w) \times v = 0$, which means $u - w$ and $v$ are collinear. Note that $v \ne 0$ (because any vector and $0$ are collinear), so this implies
$u + w = s v$ for some scalar $s$.
Similarly, $v \times w = w \times u$ implies $u + v = t w$ for some scalar $t$.  Then $u + v + w = (t+1) w = (s+1) v$.  The only way this
doesn't say $w$ and $v$ are collinear is if $t+1$ or $s+1$ is $0$, and then $u + v + w = 0$.

Comment: Is it still not true after the extra conditions I have added?

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly different angle from Robert's answer. Because $\mathbf{w}\perp\mathbf{s}\times\mathbf{w}$ for all $\mathbf{s}$ nonzero and non-parallel to $\mathbf{w}$ and the vectors are in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, we have:

$$
\mathbf{w}\perp \mathbf{u}\times \mathbf{v} \implies \mathbf{w}=a\cdot \mathbf{u} + b\cdot \mathbf{v}
$$

The first and second equation:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{v}
&=\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{w}\\
&=\mathbf{v}\times\left(a\cdot\mathbf{u}+b\cdot\mathbf{v}\right)\\
&=a\cdot\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{u}+b\cdot\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{v}\\
&=a\cdot\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{u}
\end{aligned}
$$

from which we obtain $a=-1$. Repeating for the first and third equation:

$$
\mathbf{u}\times\mathbf{v}=b\cdot\mathbf{v}\times\mathbf{u}
$$

from which we obtain $b=-1$. Therefore, we have

$$
\mathbf{w}=-\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{v}
$$